# Clean way to inject a Spring 3 bean into a JSF 2 managed bean?

Tags: spring, jsf-2, annotations

I'm migrating our current solution from JSF 1.2 to JSF 2. As I need to use the new View scope I'm using JSF 2 annotations. That forced me to inject the Spring beans using the JSF @ManagedProperty annotation instead of Spring's @Autowired

Before it was something like this:

```
@Autowired private OneService oneService
```

And now it's like:

```
@ManagedProperty(value="#{oneServiceImpl}")
private OneService oneService
```

Do you know if is there a way to annotate the managed properties without needing to state their bean name?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there isn't. JSF makes use of Expression Language (EL) to determine which class you refer by name. Using a class called [ELResolver](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/el/ELResolver.html) he takes the String passed, interprets and makes the appropriate reference. The class [SpringBeanFacesELResolver](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/web/jsf/el/SpringBeanFacesELResolver.html) provides integration between the two frameworks intercepts the request and passing it to the context of Spring, which handles the dependencies required to provide the ManagedBeans, who then passes it to the JSF's own ELResolver. So JSF needs the name of the bean to know what to inject.

Answer (score 0):

You can still use Spring with JSF 2. Just create a custom Spring scope which can then be used as the view scope for your beans.

```
@Named @Scope("view")
public class MyBean {

    @Inject
    private MyManagedProperty oneService;

    //...

}
```

Steal the implementation of the View scope here: http://cagataycivici.wordpress.com/2010/02/17/port-jsf-2-0s-viewscope-to-spring-3-0/